# How can I tell whether or not an element inside an array is a number or a word (all elements in quotes)

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

Background information: I have an array

```
this.someArray = ["Word", "123", "456"]
```

Where this.someArray is dynamically written (the array elements are not hardcoded)

I need to convert all items that are numbers into numbers (yes I realise that this might not make sense, essentially this is the result I want - where the numbers don't have quotes but leave the words as they are):

```
["Word", 123, 456]
```

So the steps I've thought in terms of how to achieve this:

1. Find out whether each element in the array is a word or number

To achieve this I have:

```
    isNumber(number) { 
      return !isNaN(parseFloat(number)) && !isNaN(number-0) 
    }
```

2. Use a for each loop to test whether each element is a word or number

   this.someArray.forEach(element => {
   this.isNumber(element)
   });
3. Write an if statement (if the element in this.someArray is a number then remove the quotes from that element)

However I'm unsure of whether step 2 is actually the correct thing to do and I'm unsure of how to write step 3

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Further info:

This is what the dynamically generated array looks like:

[image]

This is the code:

```
      this.someArray = this.biggerArray.map((n) => {
        const data = [];
        for (var key of Object.keys(n)) {
          data.push(n[key].data);
        }
        return data;
      });
```

Comment: All you need is `isNaN(Number(arrayElement))` to determine if the value is a number. Don't use `parseFloat()`. The only tricky part would deciding whether the string "NaN" should be treated as a number (because the constant `NaN` is a number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a plain `.map` would be easier - check if the string is composed of all digits with a regular expression, and if so, call `Number` on it:

```js
const arr = ["Word", "123", "456"];
const newArr = arr.map(
  str => /^\d+$/.test(str) ? Number(str) : str
);
console.log(newArr);
```

`^\d+$` means:

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `$` - end of string

If the numbers might contain decimals, then add an optional group for the decimal portion:

```js
const arr = ["Word", "123", "456", '12.45'];
const newArr = arr.map(
  str => /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(str) ? Number(str) : str
);
console.log(newArr);
```

For the array of `['Process', '1287']`, it still works as expected:

```js
const arr = ['Process', '1287'];
const newArr = arr.map(
  str => /^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/.test(str) ? Number(str) : str
);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This is accurate *if* the numeric strings are always integers.

Comment: Oddly enough it does work when I define the array like so: arr = ["Word", "123", "456", '12.45'];, however when using a dynamically generated array (added to the question) it doesn't seem to work. Is there a reason why? I'm very happy to accept the answer since it does work in general but any idea why it won't work in my case?

Comment: @One_for_all The new array in your question still looks to work just fine using the prior code, see snippet in answer

Comment: Ah I mean is there a way to apply this const arr = [["Word", "123", "456", '12.45'],  ["Word", "123", "456", '12.45'] , ["Word", "123", "456", '12.45']] for all items inside an array of arrays?

Comment: @One_for_all Map them? `arrOfArrs.map(transformArr)` where `transformArr` maps a single array

Answer (score 0):

This approach also works for decimals within quotes.

```
for (let i in someArray) {
    if (parseFloat(someArray[i])) {
        someArray[i] = parseFloat(someArray[i]);
    }
}
```

This is a shorter way of doing it.

```
for (let i in someArray) {
    parseFloat(someArray[i]) && (someArray[i] = parseFloat(someArray[i]));
}
```